# Windows Phone 8 connection check WebClient throws dreaded System.Net.WebException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm writing a Windows Phone 8 application that is designed to work online and offline. To do this it needs to be able to check for an internet connection. This is fine if there's no connection, or if there is a connection, but if the user is connected to a wifi hotspot and they haven't authenticated, then I need to return a 'no connection' status. However, even with a try catch it seems impossible to catch the System.Net.WebException error using either WebClient or HttpWebRequest. I've searched all over for solutions but none seem to work - any help would be appreciated.

Here's my connection check code:

```
public async Task<bool> tskbooCheckConnectionSimpleNoQueue()
    {
        bool booHasConnection = false;
        bool isNetwork = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        if (!isNetwork)
        {
            booHasConnection = false;
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["booHasConnection"] = false;
            return booHasConnection;
        }
        else
        {
            //actually check connection
            WebClient wcConnectionCheck = new WebClient();
            string strData = "";
            string strConnectionCheck = "https://urltocheckconnection.com/connectioncheckmethod"; 
            try
            {
                strData = await wcConnectionCheck.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(strConnectionCheck)); //exception thrown here
                if (strData.ToString().Contains("success"))
                {
                    booHasConnection = true;
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["booHasConnection"] = true;
                    return booHasConnection;
                }
                else
                {
                    booHasConnection = false;
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["booHasConnection"] = false;
                    return booHasConnection;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                booHasConnection = false;
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["booHasConnection"] = false;
                return booHasConnection;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code looks right to me. Are you sure there isn't some other exception type that is being thrown?

Comment: Yes, the code works fine if you have a connection, but if it can't connect then it throws the System.Net.WebException "Not Found". What's actually happening is the wifi proxy is redirecting any traffic and so can't resolve the service URL, hence Not Found. That's fine, but I just need to be able to handle it!

Comment: Have you checked for crazy things, like the `WebException` in your `catch` resolving to a local type instead of `System.Net.WebException`?

Comment: Unfortunately it never hits the catch - that's the problem. It breaks on `strData = await wcConnectionCheck.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(strConnectionCheck));`

Comment: If you're running in the debugger, this is expected behavior. If you hit continue, it should proceed to the `catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have catch handled exceptions turned on.

In visual studio, click the 'Debug' menu and select 'Exceptions'.

Under the 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' item, untick the 'Thrown' column.

Your debugger will no longer break, and the exception will be caught.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - you're right. I had actually tried this before by unticking the system.net.webexception. This solution worries be though:
- Once going to the catch, the code runs very slowly.
- Won't this affect all Visual Studio projects?
- Is this really the best way to handle this? Feels like an ugly hack...

Comment: What you're seeing is a 'first chance exception', this isn't a hack - the debugger is telling you an exception occurred. You don't need to know though because you are handling it correctly. I typically work with this option turned off, and only turn it on when I am actively debugging my project and want to find exceptions occurring that I'm not handling in the right location.